# How to add image fiel in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**hey hope you al doing good ...**

I'm currently facing this problem in my internship . also I am new beginner at Flutter.

i build a crud application with opt verification with fireStore Database like you seeing in the picture i was having 2 field for the Event entitles(name,date) now i need to add a picture field in itt like Event (name,date,picture) like we do in sql .
[image: event entites]

*the problem is how can i connect the fire store database withe fire cloud can someone help a brother out with a beginner tutor thanks so much .*

Comment: You can simply store the image path instead and store the image in your firebase storage .

Comment: thanks so much that was helpful and if you have an example i would appreciate it so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase storage to store files [(documentation here)](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview/).
Then its better to keep URL of these files in your fireStore database.
[this](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage) package might help.

Comment: thanks so much for your replay you just give me a flushh happy coding

Comment: go through this [stackoverlow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=Good%20answers%20are,person%20who%20asked.)